# Android studio : Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: android

Using local gradle distro : 3.2.1
Android studio : Latest
I'm getting this error : Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
How do i fix it ?
Thank you for any help and advance

```html
E:\AndroidStudio\jre\bin\java -Dgradle.home=C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1 -Dtools.jar=E:\AndroidStudio\jre\lib\tools.jar -Didea.launcher.port=7534 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=E:\AndroidStudio\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\groovy-all-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\ant-1.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\ant-launcher-1.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-base-services-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-base-services-groovy-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-cli-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-core-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-docs-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-installation-beacon-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-jvm-services-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-launcher-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-logging-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-messaging-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-model-core-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-model-groovy-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-native-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-open-api-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-process-services-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-resources-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-script-kotlin-0.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-tooling-api-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-ui-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\gradle-wrapper-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-announce-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-antlr-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-build-comparison-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-build-init-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-code-quality-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-composite-builds-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-dependency-management-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-diagnostics-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-ear-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-ide-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-ide-native-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-ide-play-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-ivy-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-jacoco-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-javascript-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-jetty-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-language-groovy-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-language-java-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-language-jvm-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-language-native-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-language-scala-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-maven-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-osgi-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-platform-base-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-platform-jvm-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-platform-native-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-platform-play-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-plugin-development-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-plugin-use-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-plugins-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-publish-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-reporting-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-resources-http-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-resources-s3-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-resources-sftp-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-scala-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-signing-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-task-cache-http-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-test-kit-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-testing-base-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-testing-jvm-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-testing-native-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\gradle-tooling-api-builders-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\gradle-3.2.1\lib\plugins\ivy-2.2.0.jar;E:\AndroidStudio\lib\idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain --build-file C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\kute-master\kute-android-app\app\build.gradle --info
Initialized native services in: C:\Users\Teodor\.gradle\native
Connected to daemon DaemonInfo{pid=12400, address=[26cff26a-bf99-42a6-b321-458633dc2438 port:63045, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1480508568373, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=d8845dbc-9033-4bd3-a221-903f5cae28b5,javaHome=E:\AndroidStudio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Teodor\.gradle\daemon,pid=12400,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}. Dispatching request Build{id=57715282-f9af-4338-9cb6-212aadad091e.1, currentDir=C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\kute-master\kute-android-app\app}.
Received result org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted@69f1a286 from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=12400, address=[26cff26a-bf99-42a6-b321-458633dc2438 port:63045, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1480508568373, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=d8845dbc-9033-4bd3-a221-903f5cae28b5,javaHome=E:\AndroidStudio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Teodor\.gradle\daemon,pid=12400,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be starting).
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 12400). The daemon log file: C:\Users\Teodor\.gradle\daemon\3.2.1\daemon-12400.out.log
Starting 37th build in daemon [uptime: 1 hrs 40 mins 31.711 secs, performance: 99%]
Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=d8845dbc-9033-4bd3-a221-903f5cae28b5,javaHome=E:\AndroidStudio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Teodor\.gradle\daemon,pid=12400,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file 'C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\kute-master\kute-android-app\app\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\kute-master\kute-android-app\app\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'app', project ':app']
Evaluating root project 'app' using build file 'C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\kute-master\kute-android-app\app\build.gradle'.


BUILD FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


Total time: 0.688 secs
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\kute-master\kute-android-app\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\kute-master\kute-android-app\app\build.gradle' line: 1
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'app'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=12400, address=[26cff26a-bf99-42a6-b321-458633dc2438 port:63045, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1480508568373, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=d8845dbc-9033-4bd3-a221-903f5cae28b5,javaHome=E:\AndroidStudio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Teodor\.gradle\daemon,pid=12400,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Build.Gradle file :

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kute.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your project level `build.gradle`(in this case `C:\Users\Teodor\Desktop\kute-master\kute-android-app\build.gradle`) has android gradle plugin inside the buildscript.dependencies block. Like so:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same symptoms, but turns out that the cause was not too glorious... I made a mistake during CVS merging that removed some important files. Therefore I had to revert to a previous commit. In my case, was not far at all. 
Hope it helps somebody someday.